# Can I add power to a USB hub through a molex connector?

Tags: usb, power-supply

I have a 5 1/4 drive bay unit that has 6 USB ports, card readers, etc, and a Molex connector passthrough.

[image]

Because there are so many USB ports, they provide very little power. Can I disconnect the power to the USB from the motherboard (for safety) then connect the 5v power from the Molex to the USB? If yes do I do the same for the ground or do I connect both grounds? I want to keep the USB data wires intact.

Comment: Would it not be easier, safer and more electrically safer to add a powered USB Hub.

Comment: Almost certainly. But that’s not the plan. I’m mounting this unit into the surface of a desktop.  The idea being to keep it as uncluttered as possible.

Comment: Do not connect both grounds.  The second ground is for 12v.  The one thing is we don't know how many amps the internal circuit board is rated to handle safety.  What is the make and model of this device?  You need a minimum of 5amps which isn't that high.  If the USB ports support PD,QC, or other charging protocols then you could have other issues since they support generally 0-20v.

Comment: Note aside from the actual USB 3 header, their is 1 USB 2.0 header with 2 port which has to be shared among 6 USB 2.0 port, bandwidth is going to also be bad.

Comment: How much power do the USB ports supply and how much do you think they should supply?  The USB ports likely only support 500ma from the 2.0 ports and 900ma from the 3.0 ports.  You would need to buy a USB power meter to confirm how much power your actually getting.   If your trying to get more power than that you will need a device that actually says it support PD,QC, or one of the dozen or so power delivery protocols.

Comment: Well as it stands i can’t charge my 12.9" iPad. Even by itself, plugged directly into my pc. It draws a lot of power. I’m hoping that this solution will also help with that. As for both grounds I meant the ground from the pc and the 5v ground from the molex. Sorry, bad description on my part. The main question is, is anything going to explode?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the amazon link I found for your device.

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B09CDPB33S](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09CDPB33S)

Your USB 3 headers directly connect to the motherboard, and you will get whatever power your motherboard provides.

You physically have 6 USB 2.0 port, but the cable on the back connects to 2 USB 2.0 port on the backside.

[image: actual image from amazon]

The zoomed in view here shows the second connector is for audio.

[image: audio]

Therefore there is one or two USB hub chips internally.  This results in them restricting the power flow to the front ports.

You would have to physically open the device, find out what hub chip(s) are being used and find the datasheet.  After finding the datasheet you could confirm whether or not it allows for power pass through or not.

However, my best educated guess is that this device probably does NOT support it.